Implementing a weighted loss function in SFTTrainer
Currently you can let SFTTrainer teach your models to learn to predict every token in your dataset, or you can let it train on "completions only", using the DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM class.
I would like something in between, where certain tokens have a higher weight than others.
I thought it would be fairly trivial, but nope.
Here's what I currently came up with (using Unsloth, so I can try this out on Google Collab):
import transformers
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from datetime import datetime
from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerBase
from typing import List, Dict, Any
from unsloth import is_bfloat16_supported
from trl import SFTTrainer

from transformers.utils import logging
logging.set_verbosity_info()
logger = logging.get_logger("transformers.modeling_utils")

class WeightedLossTrainer(SFTTrainer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        logger.info("Compute loss starts")
        
        labels = inputs.get("labels")
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        logits = outputs.get("logits")
        weight_ranges = inputs.get("weight_ranges")

        batch_size, seq_len, num_classes = logits.shape

        loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')
        total_weighted_loss = 0.0
        total_weights = 0.0

        logger.info(f"Doing {batch_size} batch sizes")

        for batch_idx in range(batch_size):
            # Collect weights and losses.
            batch_weighted_losses = []
            for start_idx, end_idx, weight in weight_ranges[batch_idx]:
                logit_chunk = logits[batch_idx, start_idx:end_idx + 1]
                label_chunk = labels[batch_idx, start_idx:end_idx + 1]

                loss = loss_fct(logit_chunk.view(-1, num_classes), label_chunk.view(-1))
                weighted_loss = loss * weight
                batch_weighted_losses.append(weighted_loss.sum())
                total_weights += weight * (end_idx - start_idx + 1)  # Total token count in this range
            
            # Sum the weighted losses for the batch.
            batch_weighted_loss_sum = torch.stack(batch_weighted_losses).sum()
            total_weighted_loss += batch_weighted_loss_sum.detach()

        # Compute the mean loss.
        mean_loss = total_weighted_loss / total_weights
        mean_loss = torch.tensor(mean_loss, dtype=torch.float32, device=logits.device, requires_grad=True)

        logger.info(f"Mean loss: {mean_loss}")

        return (mean_loss, outputs) if return_outputs else mean_loss



class WeightedDataCollator:
    def __init__(self, tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizerBase):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer

    def __call__(self, examples: List):
        all_input_ids = []
        all_attention_masks = []
        all_weight_ranges = []

        for entry in examples:
            example_input_ids = []
            example_attention_masks = []
            example_weight_ranges = []
            current_length = 0  # Initialize length counter

            for item in entry['pieces']:
                tokenized = self.tokenizer(item['text'], truncation=True, padding=False, return_tensors='pt')
                input_ids = tokenized.input_ids.squeeze()  # Get tensor, remove batch dimension
                attention_mask = tokenized.attention_mask.squeeze()  # Get tensor, remove batch dimension

                start_idx = current_length
                end_idx = start_idx + len(input_ids) - 1

                example_input_ids.append(input_ids)
                example_attention_masks.append(attention_mask)
                example_weight_ranges.append((start_idx, end_idx, item['weight']))

                current_length = end_idx + 1  # Update current length

            concatenated_input_ids = torch.cat(example_input_ids, dim=0) if example_input_ids else torch.tensor([], dtype=torch.long)
            concatenated_attention_masks = torch.cat(example_attention_masks, dim=0) if example_attention_masks else torch.tensor([], dtype=torch.long)

            pad_length = max_seq_length - len(concatenated_input_ids)  # Assuming max_length = 512 for padding if needed
            if pad_length > 0:
                concatenated_input_ids = torch.cat([concatenated_input_ids, torch.tensor([self.tokenizer.pad_token_id] * pad_length)])
                concatenated_attention_masks = torch.cat([concatenated_attention_masks, torch.tensor([0] * pad_length)])

            all_input_ids.append(concatenated_input_ids)
            all_attention_masks.append(concatenated_attention_masks)
            all_weight_ranges.append(example_weight_ranges)

            logger.info(f"All ranges: {all_weight_ranges}")

        return {
            "input_ids": torch.stack(all_input_ids),
            "attention_mask": torch.stack(all_attention_masks),
            "labels": torch.stack(all_input_ids).clone(),
            "weight_ranges": all_weight_ranges
        }

# Define data collator
data_collator = WeightedDataCollator(tokenizer=tokenizer)

# Prepare dataset for the data collator
#collated_data = data_collator(dataset)

training_args = transformers.TrainingArguments(
      per_device_train_batch_size = 2,
      gradient_accumulation_steps = 4,
      warmup_steps = 5,
      max_steps = 60,
      learning_rate = 2e-4,
      fp16 = not is_bfloat16_supported(),
      bf16 = is_bfloat16_supported(),
      logging_steps = 5,
      optim = "adamw_8bit",
      weight_decay = 0.01,
      lr_scheduler_type = "linear",
      seed = 3407,
      output_dir = "outputs",
      remove_unused_columns=False,
)

from trl import SFTTrainer
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from unsloth import is_bfloat16_supported

trainer = WeightedLossTrainer(
    model = model,
    tokenizer = tokenizer,
    train_dataset = dataset,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    max_seq_length = max_seq_length,
    dataset_num_proc = 2,
    args = training_args,
    packing=False,
    dataset_text_field='text',
    dataset_kwargs={'skip_prepare_dataset': True}
)

trainer_stats = trainer.train()

Each entry in my dataset is an object that has a single property pieces.
pieces is an array, and it contains other objects. Each object inside it has a text and a weight property.
As soon as it starts to calculate the loss, it seems to take a long while (a few seconds) until it eventually just OOMs: ran out of CUDA memory.
So what exactly am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Reduce the sizes first?

were you able to sort it out? I'm also curious
